# Google Analytics Embed API Error: uncaught exception [object Object]

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to add Google Analytics (GA) to my dashboard, and I copied exactly the code from [this article](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started).
However, I saw this error:

```
uncaught exception: [object Object] (unknown script)
```

I'm pretty sure I also copied exactly the `CLIENT_ID` provided by Google. To make it easier for people, I post my code here:

```
<section id="auth-button"></section>
<section id="view-selector"></section>
<section id="timeline"></section>


<script>
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fjs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(cb){this.q.push(cb)}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics')};
}(window,document,'script'));
</script>

<script>
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {


  var CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';

  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    container: 'auth-button',
    clientid: CLIENT_ID,
  });


  var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
    container: 'view-selector'
  });


  var timeline = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    reportType: 'ga',
    query: {
      'dimensions': 'ga:date',
      'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'yesterday',
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'LINE',
      container: 'timeline'
    }
  });


  gapi.analytics.auth.on('success', function(response) {
    viewSelector.execute();
    console.log(response);
  });

  viewSelector.on('change', function(ids) {
    var newIds = {
      query: {
        ids: ids
      }
    }
    timeline.set(newIds).execute();
  });
});
</script>
```

Did anybody meet this before?

Answer (score 0):

Encoutered the problem today.

You may add

```
window.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
  console.log('err', event);
});
```

to catch the potential error.

For me was occuring because of

```
gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    container: 'auth-button',
    clientid: CLIENT_ID,
});
```

Error shown was (truncated)

```
error: Object { error: "idpiframe_initialization_failed... Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and whitelist this origin for your project's client ID" }
```

Comment: Cheers, I will have a look and give you the error later

Answer (score 0):

I also wondered what this could be. Firefox was not helpful in the console at all. But Chrome gave the full error message.

I solved it by going to the API console and adding the domain name of my website to Authorized JavaScript origins. Wait a few minutes for the change to propagate and it will work.